# как грамотно писать окончание?

Tags: грамотная-речь

как правильно писать" участвовалО или участвовалИ восемь команд"?

Answer (score 3):

> "участвовалО или участвовалИ восемь команд"?

Оба варианта правильны.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь возможны оба варианта. Ед.ч. указывает на совместное действие, а мн.ч. - на раздельное.

Answer (score 2):

Если это только статистика, то достаточно обезличивающего "-о". Если вслед за этим вы перечисляете команды, для логического связывания предпочтительно "-и".

Answer (score 2):

Если сказуемое находится в **препозиции** (особенно если существительное  **неодушевленное**), то предпочтительнее использовать форму ед. числа:

В турнире участвовало восемь команд".